# Force Word grammar / spell checking

Tags: microsoft-word

I've created a 200+ page Computer science project write-up, with a lot of code.

Recently, word started refusing to spell/grammar check the document, due to the amount of unrecognised text.

What can I do? I looked through a few paragraphs and saw that I had been making errors without even noticing. How can I force word to check the contents?

I have 12GB of RAM, is that not enough!?

How can I exclude the font of the code, it's all consolas/lucida console.

Would I have to manually go through each code paragraph and mark it as "do not check?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd edit the style of your code paragraphs, changing the language (look for the Format button in the bottom left of the Modify Style dialog) so it's either marked as *Do not check spelling or grammar* or else as a language that you don't have the spellchecker for (i.e. one with no checkmark in the list).

If you're not using styles, I would suggest you should be. You should be able to create one, then apply it using Find and Replace, by find the fonts in question (probably one at a time) and replacing with the style you've created.

Possible caveat: IIRR, styling your code removes syntax highlighting.

---

Edit: if you don't want to get into styles, Find and Replace might do what you need: **find** by font (*Find* tab → *Format* button → *Font...* item → choose Consolas); **replace** with new language settings (*Replace* tab → *Format* button → *Language...* item → either check *Do not check spelling or grammar*, or choose a language without an ABC checkmark). Repeat for Lucida Console.

Comment: I'm done for...

Comment: I'm literally going to copy the last few pages into a new document, and work from there.